# Recommended software to create a simple Android app?

Tags: android, python, java, software-development, game-development

I just want to create a simple Android word game app similar to something like **4 Pics 1 Word.**

I have basic knowledge of **Python, Java and Scratch** and so I have already researched about Kivy and Pygame but I don't think these apps would suit me as I would want something that is simpler (preferrably a developing software with a **GUI**).

Feel free to leave any suggestions...

Answer (score 1):

You need the Android SDK.  Full blow IDE for coding plus a GUI designer plus the needed libs/jars/etc as well as an emulator so you can actually run your code without hacking and rooting a phone/tablet.

Harder question to answer (and no stack for it that I'm aware of) is a good book with a good walk through tutorial on not just using the IDE but making basic apps.